# How to add a column to a multi-dimesional vector (C++)?

Tags: c++, vector

This might be easy but I just cant find a solution. I created a 2D vector like this:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix;
vector<int> row;

for (int i = 0; i < x;i++) {
    row.push_back(i);
}
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    matrix.push_back(row);
}
```

The problem I have is that I now wanna add rows and columns as I need them because I might run out of matrix space over time but I don't know how to do it. The rows are easy I can just .push_back another row to the bottom end of the matrix...but I have no Idea how to add another column.

I'm sorry if this question is super stupid but I'm not that experienced in programming yet and I couldn't find anything on the particular problem of adding columns to a 2D vector.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you wanna to add 1 more dimension to vector?

Comment: The column number is gonna be the size of the vector rows

Comment: You can iterate through each row and push_back a new element at the end of each row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to your code, the idea is to loop over each row in the matrix and push a new element onto each vector. Together, all of these elements are a new column.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Initialize a 3x3 matrix
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;
    vector<int> row;
    int x = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        row.push_back(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        matrix.push_back(row);
    }

    // Add a column; the matrix is now 3x4
    int newElement = 3;

    for (auto &row : matrix) {
        row.push_back(newElement);
    }

    // Print the matrix
    for (auto &row : matrix) {
        for (auto &cell : row) {
            cout << cell << ' ';
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You'll likely want to separate this code into functions.

Comment: I'll emphasize "throw this code into separate functions" and suggest one further improvement: create a wrapper class to help encapsulate and abstract away the inner workings. That way if you have to make changes in the future, you can do it without ripping up much, if any, any client code.

Comment: Thank you this is what I wanted to do but can u explain what exactly the for (auto &row : matrix) thing does :)

Comment: [That's a range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). It's a little cleaner than the traditional for loop, but feel free to stick to traditional counter loops if you're accustomed to them; the logic is the same.

Answer (score 1):

vector<vector<T>> is a BAD way to implement a matrix. Well - it may not be a bad backend implementation, but its a bad public API.

I'd suggest using some library designed to support a Matrix. A few come to mind:

```
https://github.com/SophistSolutions/Stroika/blob/V2.1-Release/Library/Sources/Stroika/Foundation/Math/LinearAlgebra/Matrix.h
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html
http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#part_classes
```

or write your own and implement the basic functions directly.

Comment: I upvoted because abstracting *is* the correct way to learn programmation, but what the user gave was maybe a minimal working version of his problem !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function that will add a column to your matrix at a specified position:

```
void add_column(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& matrix,
                const std::vector<int>& column, std::size_t position)
{
    if(matrix.size() < position || position < 0) return; // check for position correctness

    std::size_t index = 0;
    for(auto& row : matrix){
        row.insert(row.begin() + position, column[index++]);
    }
}
```

For example, given a matrix:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
```

and initializing it like so:

```
std::vector<int> column;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    column.push_back(3);
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    matrix.push_back(column);
}
```

you end with with 3x3 matrix of `3`s. Now, adding a column in between the first and the second one:

```
add_column(matrix, std::vector<int>({9, 9, 9}), 1);
```

and printing it:

```
for (auto& row : matrix) {
    for (const auto x : row) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

You end up with:

```
3 9 3 3
3 9 3 3
3 9 3 3
```

Comment: @justTom And that's exactly what this code does. Additionally, it permits to specift the exact column number where you want to insert a new one. I, however, don't quite understand your "*and more dynamic*" comment. Care to elaborate? Also - his method allows you to add a column of identical numbers. My solution offers adding a column made of any `int`s